# JavaScript object - error when calling a method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Within one of the methods of a JavaScript object I'm building - *open()* -, there is a call to a previously defined method of the same object - *close()*. When calling the *open()* method, I get the following error:

"***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'close'***"

Bellow is my code:

```
var lightbox = {};
lightbox.close = function(){
    // Some code here
};
lightbox.open = function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        lightbox.close();
    });
}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you by any chance doing something else with the `lightbox` object in the same scope?

Comment: I was indeed and didn't realize it. Many thanks! It solved the problem. Add the answer so I can approve it, please.